# Open GL + CUDA с++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, cuda

Пытался запустить пример метода sph на cuda https://github.com/finallyjustice/sphfluid/tree/master/SPH_GPU_2D_v1, но при запуске окно opengl не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: карточка и драйверы стоят? Ошибки пишет?

Comment: Все драйвера установил, ошибок не пишет. В версии без cuda частицы выводятся в окно, с cuda, окно Opengl закрашивается фоном, но частицы не отрисовываются